# Are blocked callers notified

Tags: iphone, ios, phone.app

When you block a caller are they notified they are blocked?

Answer (score 3):

No the caller is not notified if you block a contact from an iOS menus and they try calling you. The call rings through normally on their side and would be routed to your voicemail.  A section in voicemail will appear that is called 'Blocked Messages' where any voicemails left by callers you have blocked are kept.